# Odoo: Model based on sql view, xml view doesn't show anything

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am trying to make a report where the user selects a product from a drop down list and it shows a table that has the following columns
create date, stock quantity, incoming and outgoing quantities, supplier/customer , and price
since it has to get each field from a different model, i had to use sql views, but then when i load the odoo view it doesn't show any of the fields, i made sure the sql statments of the view works fine, and when examining the datatbase, the view is created, still nothing shows up on the view

code below

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, tools, _

class ProductProfileReportView(models.Model):
    _name = "product.profile.report"
    _auto = False

    action_type = fields.Char(string="Type")
    create_date = fields.Date(string="Date")
    invoice_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="custom.purchase", string="Invoice", required=False, )
    qty = fields.Integer(string="Qty")
    supplier_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="custom.supplier", string="Supplier", required=False, )
    price = fields.Float(string="Price")

    @api.model_cr
    def init(self):
        """ Event Question main report """
        tools.drop_view_if_exists(self._cr, 'product_profile_report')
        self._cr.execute(""" CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW product_profile_report AS (
            select p.id as id,
            'Purchase' as action_type,
            pu.create_date as create_date,
            pu.id as invoice_id,
            pul.qty as qty,
            s.id as supplier_id,
            p.sell_price as price
            from
            custom_product p
            inner join custom_purchase_line pul
            on p.id = pul.product_id
            inner join custom_purchase pu
            on pul.purchase_id = pu.id
            inner join custom_supplier s
            on pu.supplier_id = s.id)""")
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="form_product_profile_report" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.profile.report.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.profile.report</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <fields name="action_type"/>
                        <fields name="create_date"/>
                        <fields name="invoice_id"/>
                        <fields name="qty"/>
                        <fields name="supplier_id"/>
                        <fields name="price"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_product_profile_report" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">product profile report</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.profile.report</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create"></p>
        </field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="report_item" name="Reports" parent="custom_product_root"/>
    <menuitem id="product_profile_report_submenu" name="Product Profile" parent="report_item"
              action="action_product_profile_report"/>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized where the problem is, i didn't add a tree view in the xml file